# Are there any banks in Canada that don't charge large fees for transactions in foreign currencies?

Tags: canada, banking

Looking at the offers from Canadian banks it seems that the choice is quite poor for people who travel a lot. Every bank seems to charge 2.5% on top of dubious exchange rates for every transaction in a foreign currency, plus there are extra fees for foreign ATMs.

I thought I could get around the system by simply wiring CAD to [Revolut](https://www.revolut.com/), but here again every bank charges at least 30 CAD for transfers to foreign countries, so I would again overpay a lot just to use my own money. I guess I could just wire 3,000+ CAD at a time to Revolut, lowering the transaction fee to a reasonable 1%, but I'd rather not keep so much money in that account.

Are there any banks that don't have excessive fees for foreign currencies?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because it is "price-shopping".

Comment: I think the question was poorly extended with all the $$$ and %%%, but the legitimate question still remains: What's the best way to get money transfered from and into the Canadian banking system - which is very very painful.

Comment: Considering how large the HK community is in Canada, have you looked at offerings by the HK banks there, especially HSBC and Standard Chartered?

Comment: @dda I've found an option that works will all banks and for all currencies - see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used https://www.transfermate.com to move money from Europe to Canada. I found it was the best option. There is also http://www.xe.com/.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on Steffen's answer - it seems that the best way is to do the following:

- Use TransferWise to convert CAD to EUR, currently the fee for that is 1%
- Transfer the EUR to a Revolut account and then spend it comission free wherever you are in the world

This allows you to completely sidestep the local banking infrastructure when it comes to foreign operations.